# django rest framework many to many field not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I need your help regarding something weird.

I have the following models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True, default="")
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=profile_image_upload_path)

class Skill(models.Model):
    profiles = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=skill_image_upload_path)
    is_tech_skill = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and the following serializer:

```
class SkillSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profiles = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Profile.objects.all(), many=True)
    class Meta:
        model=Skill
        fields=['name', 'image', 'is_tech_skill', 'expertise']

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    skill_list = SkillSerializer(read_only=True, many=True,)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'image', 'skill_list')
        depth = 2
```

when I do GET request for the profile I do not see any skills:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hQCW.png)

I added two skills to this profile from django admin panel.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no **"profiles"** in your **serializer**.
**1.**  You named your ManyToMany to **profiles** and didn't use it anywhere,after you named an another field to **"profiles"**.
**2.**  I think you need to add it into your **fields** in **serializer**
**3.**  Add **related_name** to your **ManyToManyField**